# Yii: returnurl is reset every time user logs in

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm using

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($url);
```

to set the return url and it is set once user successfully logged in.

But when session timed out, and user relogins, it doesn't fetch the URL what was previously set. I fetch the URL by using

```
$returnurl = Yii::app()->user->getReturnUrl();
```

But it returns the default URL not the one which was set.

Seems like the returnurl is completely reset every time user logs in.

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Yii Framework: 1.1.10

Comment: this is expected behavior, but depending on what is $url, i.e a constant or variable, you might be able to do something else, so what is your ultimate requirement? and give some info about $url, how you extract/generate it? edit: you fetch by get or set? typo?

Comment: @bool.dev sorry for the typo in question. During the user session, getReturnUrl returns the value perfectly.

what I want is, when user's session timed out and user relogin, it should go the the URL it set before time out. This is all I need.

Comment: i think even in session timeouts the loginRequired function is called, which sets this returnUrl, so you have to figure out a way to set the url before login, and not after login

Comment: @bool.dev returnUrl is something where user was last seen, how can it be set before login? it should be set on each page a user visits (except ajax calls). Or am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: the loginRequired function sets the returnUrl by checking the url of the request, so if a user wanted to do something(by visiting some url) that required logging in, that url is set as the returnUrl(hence before logging in). I do not know what happens when session timeout occurs(atm). I could probably help further if i see your login function, and also the source of `$url`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest read answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270875/using-yii-returnurl-on-nginx-server/14913929), Actual problem is that the getReturnUrl() sets the returnUrl to default so you should set the returnUrl manually before each action which needs login & you should do that by extending the CWebUser and overriding the loginRequired function.

Comment: i agree that the other question has the correct answer but you should mark it as a duplicate, rather then actually answering the question like this