# Yii-Eauth redirect after login

Tags: php, facebook, yii, yii-extensions

Currently once I login using facebook it will redirect me to `site/index page`.

Ok. Now my question is, If I open page `example/view&id=1` and i click the facebook login button, what shall i do in order for the page to redirect back to `example/view&id=1` instead of `site/index page`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647222/yii-returnurl-function).

```
if (Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer != 'http://www.example.com/user/login')
{
    Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
}
```